# Understanding Wikipedia Title Dump Format

Tags: format, wikipedia

I downloaded the latest list of article titles from Wikipedia. It appears to contain some sort of markup but I can't seem to find any documentation to help me understand "how" or "what" can be stripped. The file is "enwiki-latest-all-titles.gz" and can be downloaded here:

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/

I could naively strip out all punctuation, etc., based on my own observations of the text file but it would be better to have more information about the data so that it can be handled in a meaningful way.

Comment: I don't see any markup there. Could you explain what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

That's not markup, it's a list of [page_title](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Page_title). Spaces are converted to underscores etc.